# How to plot specific, and corresponding elements of two lists

Tags: python, list, datetime, matplotlib

Say I have two lists one called date and one called prcp.

```
date = [datetime.datetime(1948, 1, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1948, 1, 2, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1948, 1, 3, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1948, 1, 4, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1948, 1, 5, 0, 0)]

prcp = [0.47,0.59,0.42,0.31,0.17]
```

These values correspond with each other and I could plot them with pyplot like the following:

```
pyplot.scatter(date,prcp)
```

This would plot date on the x axis and prcp on the y axis. great.

Say I get rid of any elements outside of a specified date period so that date becomes:

```
date = [datetime.datetime(1948, 1, 2, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1948, 1, 3, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1948, 1, 4, 0, 0)]
```

If I now go to plot the data just for my newly reduced list of dates, pyplot errors out with:

```
ValueError: x and y must be the same size
```

How do I get the prcp list such that I can plot it with the corresponding date values?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use filter using `index()`.

Example:

```
>>> date = [datetime.datetime(1948, 1, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1948, 1, 2, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1948, 1, 3, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1948, 1, 4, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1948, 1, 5, 0, 0)]
>>> prcp = [0.47,0.59,0.42,0.31,0.17]
>>> selected_dates = [datetime.datetime(1948, 1, 2, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1948, 1, 3, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1948, 1, 4, 0, 0)]
>>> selected_prcp = [prcp[date.index(d)] for d in selected_dates]
>>> selected_prcp
[0.59, 0.42, 0.31]
```

You could filter more efficiently based on how you select the dates. The above assumes that `selected_dates` is an arbitrary subset of unique elements from `date`.

Answer (score 0):

- Convert the lists to `numpy.arrays`, and use `Boolean` masking to select the data, which is a fast vectorized operation.
- See [Numpy API Reference: Boolean array indexing](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing)

```py
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

# specify the data
date = np.array([datetime(1948, 1, 1, 0, 0), datetime(1948, 1, 2, 0, 0),
                 datetime(1948, 1, 3, 0, 0), datetime(1948, 1, 4, 0, 0), datetime(1948, 1, 5, 0, 0)])
prcp = np.array([0.47, 0.59, 0.42, 0.31, 0.17])

# create a Boolean mask
mask = (date > datetime(1948, 1, 1, 0, 0)) & (date < datetime(1948, 1, 5, 0, 0))

# display the mask
print(mask)
[out]:
array([False,  True,  True,  True, False])

# select data from date and prcp
selected_date = date[mask]
selected_prcp = prcp[mask]

# display selected_date and selected_prcp
print(selected_date)
[out]:
array([datetime.datetime(1948, 1, 2, 0, 0),
       datetime.datetime(1948, 1, 3, 0, 0),
       datetime.datetime(1948, 1, 4, 0, 0)], dtype=object)

print(selected_prcp)
[out]:
array([0.59, 0.42, 0.31])
```

### Plot the data

- The default datetime format of the x-axis is `'%m-%d %H'` for this short range of time, so the format is updated to include the year.

```py
plt.plot(selected_date, selected_prcp, marker='o')
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H'))
plt.show()
```

[image]